# FFMPEG - Batch combination of H.264 video and separate .WAV audio in Windows

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I am a first-time ffmpeg user trying to mux h.264 .mp4 video with separate/secondary .wav audio, without re-encoding anything on the video side. Would like the final audio to come out as .aac (same codec as the audio on the h.264 file).

Essentially, I just want to layer an additional audio track (commentary) of equivalent length onto the video. I'm trying to get around Premiere's inability to import h.264 properly by editing the .wav audio separately and combining it with the original file without ever running it through Premiere or any editor. This program seems to be the best way to do it quickly.

I would be doing this in batches, so any suggestions on how to queue up multiple jobs would be appreciated. Only queuing advice I've found used Linux code.

If you have the time to answer, explain it like I'm 5, please. I am an experienced user, but totally new to this command-line-oriented way of working with content. Not sure I'm doing *anything* right.

Also: I'm using Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic FFmpeg command line for your required use is

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.wav -map 0 -map 1:a -c:v copy -c:a:0 copy -c:a:1 aac video-new.mp4
```

`-map 0` means include all streams from the first input - FFmpeg index starts from zero. Similarly, `map 1:a` means include all audio streams from the 2nd input. `-map 1` would have sufficed since WAV files contain only audio streams.

`-c:v copy` means that any and all video streams being included in the output should be copied, so no re-encoding.

`-c:a:0 copy` means the first audio stream in the **output** should be copied as well. The order of output streams here is decided by the order of the map arguments. Since `-map 0` is placed first, the audio and video streams from that file will be stacked first in the output. So, the first audio stream in the output will be the one from the first input i.e. video.mp4

`-c:a:1 aac` means encode the second audio stream in the output with the (native) AAC encoder.

---

On Windows, you can use the [Avanti](http://www.avanti.arrozcru.org/) GUI front-end to carry out batch operations. Read the link for setup instructions - pretty straightforward.

Your main GUI window settings should look like this:

[image]

After you perform a single job from the main window, you can load the Job Control Manager, available from the drop-down menu when you click on the top-left icon.

That should look like this:

[image: Avanti Job Manager]

For each corresponding video/audio pair you add, make sure to unmark the audio file so that Avanti knows it's part of the same job as the video entry above it. Select your destination path (4th icon at top from left) to be different than the folder containing your source files. Avanti will the name the output file the same as the first input (the video) so you'll be in for a nasty surprise if you don't take care of this.

That pretty much covers it.

Comment: This is SO helpful. Thanks for the link to Avanti; if this ends up working, the GUI will make streamlining my workflow so much more straightforward.

Where I am still having an issue is that I need the original audio to be preserved so that the commentary track I'm layering in plays alongside it. So far, whether using this GUI or simple command line prompts before I posted this... I have been unable to accomplish this.

Comment: Then the source audio needs to be merged with the commentary. The command would be `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.wav -filter_complex "[0:a][1]amix[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]"  -c:v copy -c:a aac video-new.mp4`

Comment: That worked perfectly with the test files! If it works with my full-length videos, you've just saved me so much time. Thank you so much!

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks again for your help. Your exact directions perfectly accomplish what I needed and I will be using this for the foreseeable future in all of my content. Thank you SO much.

Comment: Hi Mulvya. I'm seeking your wisdom, hopefully for the last time. Really tried to find a solution before coming back to this thread.I've been successfully using this technique for a few months, but have noticed that, in some cases, I get the following error: "Input buffer exhausted before END element found."

When this error happens, it offsets my commentary by milliseconds. When it happens multiple times, it noticeably offsets the commentary to each video. Any idea how to prevent this from happening in avanti?

Comment: That error message is not related to Avanti, but the AAC decoder. The bug that produces that message was fixed some time ago. Update your version of ffmpeg and try.

Comment: Thank you. Any suggestions on the best place to get the latest build? I tried updating the ffmpeg and ffplay .exes per avanti's instructions, but to no avail.

Comment: Zeranoe is standard: https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/. If you updated it from there and it still happens, then those video files have malformed audio streams.

Comment: Interesting. I don't believe I used that site, so I'll try that next. This error doesn't occur on every audio/commentary stream I'm muxing. Just some. May be hard to pinpoint where any malformation issues could be coming from.

Comment: Unfortunately, that was not the problem. Still receiving the error; can't really fathom how the audio streams could be malformed for some instances but not for others.

Comment: The audio stream is malformed in the video, not your commentary. For such videos, first attempt is to encode both streams: use `-c:a:0 aac`. You will still get the error, but see if the sync is ok in the result.